# Populating model properties dynamically from a javascript call

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

**Problem Description:**

1] I have a model with country and city properties

```
class UserReportedData(db.Model):
  #country selected by the user, this will also populate the drop down list on the html page
  country = db.StringProperty(default='Afghanistan',choices=['Afghanistan','Aring land    
  Islands','Albania'])
  #city selected by the user
  city = db.StringProperty()
```

Associated form

```
class UserReportedDataForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = UserReportedData
```

2] With help from stackoverflow (thanks Chris, posting: [GeoIP with google app engine and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369795/geoip-with-google-app-engine-and-python)), i have figured out how to use javascript in the html page to find out the country and city for a user. The following code is successfully able to print the values of country and city on the page

```
<!-- including the  geoip javascript library -->
<script  
  src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"
  type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.geoip_country_name) {
    document.write(geoip_country_name())
    document.write(geoip_city())
   }
</script>
```

3] Now when the page is displayed the country and city text box and default values are coming from the django form (sorry cant  post a image because of restrictions)

**Question:**

I want the country and city data of the user to be filled in the country and city text box. So, somehow the python form or model should be able to call the javascript code and get the country and city data for the user.

Thanks,

[EDIT#1] Edit based on the approach suggested by @Haochi

The following are the id's that are generated by the djangoforms

```
<select name="country" id="id_country">
<input type="text" name="city" id="id_city" />
```

Tried the following javascript in the html page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.geoip_country_name) {
     document.getElementById("id_country").value = geoip_country_name();
     document.getElementById("id_city").value = geoip_city();
     document.write("this is a javasctipt print"); /* this prints properly*/
     document.write(document.getElementById("id_country").value);
     document.write(document.getElementById("id_city").value);
    }
  </script>
```

This however, didn't fill in the values for id_country and id_city text fields appropriately.

[EDIT#3] This is how the HTML file looks like, I have now moved the GEOIP calculation from server side to the client side

```
<!-- Text box for city, later on in the design this will be a drop down box -->
<p> Select City: </p>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="city" id="city"> 
  <!-- By default, we will select users city -->
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
     document.getElementById("city").value = geoip_city()
  </script>     
</div>  

<p> Select Country: </p>
<select name="selCountry" id="country">
<!-- By default, we will select users country -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    document.write("<option value=\"" + geoip_country_name() + "\" selected>"
</script>
<option value="United States">
    United States
 </option>
 <option value="United Kingdom">
    United Kingdom
 </option>
```

I believe the best practice is to move all javascript to a separate file , i need to try this out and modify the HTML code accordingly.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Do you want the values you've retrieved displayed on the client, stored on the server, or displayed in a form on the client, so that the user can submit it to the server?

Comment: I want the geoip country and city to be calculated in the server code and then the server code can automatically select those in the drop down boxes. I am now thinking calling a javascript function from the server code might be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your IDs for those two inputs are country and city:

```
document.getElementById("country").value = geoip_country_name()
document.getElementById("city").value = geoip_city()
```

Comment: Thanks @Haochi, the id of the country field is "id_country" and city is "id_city". But the javascript function is unable to find these id's. This might be because he js executes before the table is printed on the html page. Please refer to 'EDIT#1' in the original post regarding the item that i tried based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Haochi for providing the javascript example and Thanks Chris for explaining the Client server concept and reviewing my python code.I have now removed the Python class ( since it will execute on the server thereby giving wrong information) and have mode the GEOIP calculation on the client side. Currently all the javasctipt resides in the html file, but i will follow @Hacohi example and move the javascript to a new file. I will ping you guys back if i have difficulties

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following python class to find the country and city for the user. 
This is working, if someone finds any issues or somethings that can be changed for efficiency, please let me know

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

#class that is used for geo ip functionality of the application
class GeoIpLocator:

#method that will return the country city dictionary based on users GeoIP location
#dictionary format {"country_name": "USA", "city":"chicago"}
def get_country_city_dictionary(self):
    url = "http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        keep = ['country_name', 'city']
        results = dict([x for x in re.findall("geoip_(.*?)\(.*?\'(.*?)\'", result.content) if x[0] in keep])
        results.update({'source': 'mmind'})
        if results:
            return results
        else:
            return {}
```

[EDIT#1] This will not work and will return the IP of the server on which the python app loads up, thanks to @Calvin for pointing this out.

Comment: This may work on the dev_appserver, but won't work when deployed.  geoip.js finds the location of the machine that requested geoip.js. When deployed this will be returning the location of the App Engine server that is making the urlfetch request, not the end user's machine.

Comment: Thanks @Calvinn for the response. I understood what you said.Is there a way to change the code to get the users location?, can we get the remote ip addr?

Comment: I can't tell your level of experience here, but there seems to be a bit of client/server confusion going on. The jsfiddle example that Haochi posted yesterday should successfully population the client-side form for a user. The server won't know anything about this event (and your UserReportedData model will be empty) until either you send the info to the server using AJAX, or the user sends the info by clicking a submit button.

Comment: Thanks @Calvin for explaining the concept of client and server, i have a better understanding now. I have removed the GEOIP calculation from the server side and have moved the call to the client side.

Comment: @lance if you are doing it on server-side, you should probably look into IP-to-Location APIs such as [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) and [HostIP](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) by passing in the user's IP ([remote_addr](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html) if you are using GAE's webapp).

Comment: @Haochi, which one is better?, to do the GEOIP work on the client side or the server side. Please refer EDIT#3 in my main post for the item i tried based on the answer you gave given.